# Unitils @InjectInto - How is it processed?

Tags: java, mockito, unitils

Could anyone please share with me how Unitils @InjectInto or @InjectIntoByType annotations are being processed?

I have checked UnitilsJUnit4.class, which is required for processing this annotation.  That in turn needs UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class which extends JUnit4ClassRunner.  AFAIK,   UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner does not have any implementation on how Unitils processes the  annotation @InjectInto.

The basic idea behind this question - This annotation does not support injection of Mockito mocks.  I just want to check if it is possible to to add some implementation that can do this.  If there is any other direct solution that integrates Mockito with Unitils, even that is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah Unitils doesn't support Mockito. However Mockito comes with handy mock injection utility annotations.

You could write in your JUnit test something like that :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MessageEchoerTest {
    @Mock Message message;
    @InjectMocks MessageEchoer messageEchoer;
}
```

Note that it only works with mockito mocks or spies.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  That is a nice piece of information, but, @ InjectMock works only when we have a setter or constructor based injection in the CUT... but, in my case, I am using EJB3.x which does not need these. So, it may be an additional overhead in my case, to write a setter method in the CUT for mock injection.

Comment: Actually, Mockito 1.8.5 does field injection. Version 1.9 adds it all with setter injection then field injection if setter injection is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is processed in the Injection module (see `org.unitils.inject.InjectModule` and the classes inside `org.unitils.inject.util` package). Unfortunately i cannot give you the specific answer. For further information you have to debug or wait for additional answers ;)